# Transferring only tables from Microsoft Word to Excel through automation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, automated-builds

Is there a way that I can automate the copying of information from Microsoft Word tables to Microsoft Excel tables?

Comment: what do you mean?  You have a table in Excel that when changes are made you want updated to in Word?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very much possible. As I [demonstrated](https://superuser.com/a/558131/138343) just yesterday, you can use Word and Excel automation via VBScript to do anything VBA supports. Try the following VBS script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objWord, objDoc, objExcel, objSheet, tbl, srcRow, dstRow, col, cell

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\MyDoc.docx", False, True ' path, confirmconversions, readonly
Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveSheet

dstRow = 0
For Each tbl In objDoc.Tables
    For srcRow = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        col = 0
        For Each cell In tbl.Rows(srcRow).Cells
            col = col + 1
            objSheet.Cells(dstRow+srcRow, col).Value = Left(cell.Range.Text, Len(cell.Range.Text)-1)
        Next
    Next
    dstRow = dstRow + SrcRow
Next

objWord.Quit 0 ' wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set objWord = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\MyBook.xlsx"
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objSheet = Nothing

MsgBox "All table data copied from document to workbook!"
```